# EXCEPT query in SQL

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am doing an except query in SQL like this

Q1 EXCEPT Q2 EXCEPT Q3

Where Q1, Q2 and Q3 are sub-query.
I just want to know what will be its output, (Q1-Q2)-Q3 or Q1-(Q2-Q3)? and if 2nd, how to get 1st one as output?

Comment: This would be a lot easier with actual code.

Comment: Wrap them in brackets, as you suggest in your question.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the output will be?

Comment: [sscce](http://sscce.org/) please

Comment: Each Q1, Q2 and Q3 is a subquery of form SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...  .

Comment: @AlKepp - They most certainly **are not**, in the same sense that `(1-2)-3 != 1-(2-3)`.

Comment: @AlKepp - For any query `Q`, `(Q except Q) except Q` produces zero rows whereas `Q except (Q except Q)` produces the exact same rows that `Q` produces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an installation of DB2, but in PostgreSQL, `Q1 except Q2 except Q3` appears to be interpolated as `(Q1 except Q2) except Q3` (note:  `generate_series(m,n)` is a function found in PostgreSQL that generates a single column of integer values from `m` to `n` (where `m<n`, of course)):

```
select generate_series(1,10) except select generate_series(5,15) except select generate_series(10,20);


 generate_series
-----------------
               1
               2
               3
               4
(4 rows)

select * from (select generate_series(1,10) except select generate_series(5,15))a except select generate_series(10,20);


 generate_series
-----------------
               1
               2
               3
               4
(4 rows)

select generate_series(1,10) except select * from (select generate_series(5,15) except select generate_series(10,20))a;


 generate_series
-----------------
               1
               2
               3
               4
              10
(5 rows)
```

However, it's best to use parentheses to make certain that the order of evaluation is how you want it.

Comment: I upvoted due to the suggestion for parens for clarity. Strongly agree.  Anytime you have to stop and think without them that is bad.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL-92 Standard confirms (Annex C) what should be fairly intuitive: in the absence of parentheses, both occurrences of the `EXCEPT` in the sample code will (obviously) be at the same level of precedence, in which case they shall be evaluated in left-to-right order.

Out of interest, the precedence of `EXCEPT`, `INTERSECT` and `UNION` (parentheses aside) is implementation dependent, so consult the SQL product's documentation. However, a quick google seems to suggest that most SQL products (including DB2) have `EXCEPT` and `UNION` at the same level of precedence and `INTERSECT` at a higher level of precedence.